# which way is faster to add jquery to your project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which of the following way is faster and best to add jquery file,

1. add jquery file into project with link like below,

   ```
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
   ```
2. download jquery file and then add that local file.

Comment: Of course , second option is best. Because if you download the file , then no need to depend on https always. 
And if you use CDN , Network should be work , otherwise "undefined Jquery ' problem will be raised.

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile:

```
#Rails jQuery 
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In assets/javascriptapplication.js

```
//= require jquery3
```

or

```
//= require jquery2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CDN`, it will be faster but will be slower for the first time(if not loaded already). Once `CDN` is loaded, it will always run faster.

But there is a drawback of `CDN` if the `host` removes that file that will give raise to error of `JQuery not found`. To avoid that using gem or downloading is preferred.

Conclusion: both ways have their `pros` and `cons` you have to pick one yourself.